# Upload speed very slow in Ubuntu 18.04.6 while download speed is normal

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, downloads, upload

I bought a new 1GB/s server from OneProvider and installed `Ubuntu 18.04.6` on it.

The upload speed from ssh or FTP is very good, but the download speed is about 100kb/s from ssh, FTP and I tried to install Nginx and download from it but it's also about 100kb/ps.

All attempts from more than 5 devices from different locations some of these tried were from another server in the same network with (wget) but all attempts did not exceed the speed of 150kb/s.

this is (`ip a`) output :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:ae:52:ca:0f:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet (serverip)/24 brd 62.210.207.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d6ae:52ff:feca:f6e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:ae:52:ca:0f:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

(`ethtool eno1`) output :

```
Settings for eno1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: on
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: d
        Link detected: yes
```

(`ethtool -S eno1`) output :

```
NIC statistics:
     rx_bytes: 67518474469
     rx_error_bytes: 0
     tx_bytes: 1939892582744
     tx_error_bytes: 0
     rx_ucast_packets: 457688996
     rx_mcast_packets: 1105671
     rx_bcast_packets: 743858
     tx_ucast_packets: 1341579130
     tx_mcast_packets: 12
     tx_bcast_packets: 4
     tx_mac_errors: 0
     tx_carrier_errors: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_align_errors: 0
     tx_single_collisions: 0
     tx_multi_collisions: 0
     tx_deferred: 0
     tx_excess_collisions: 0
     tx_late_collisions: 0
     tx_total_collisions: 0
     rx_fragments: 0
     rx_jabbers: 0
     rx_undersize_packets: 0
     rx_oversize_packets: 0
     rx_64_byte_packets: 4346996
     rx_65_to_127_byte_packets: 430360977
     rx_128_to_255_byte_packets: 1072678
     rx_256_to_511_byte_packets: 420201
     rx_512_to_1023_byte_packets: 250311
     rx_1024_to_1522_byte_packets: 23087362
     rx_1523_to_9022_byte_packets: 0
     tx_64_byte_packets: 899130
     tx_65_to_127_byte_packets: 11634758
     tx_128_to_255_byte_packets: 2699608
     tx_256_to_511_byte_packets: 3443633
     tx_512_to_1023_byte_packets: 7211982
     tx_1024_to_1522_byte_packets: 1315690035
     tx_1523_to_9022_byte_packets: 0
     rx_xon_frames: 0
     rx_xoff_frames: 0
     tx_xon_frames: 0
     tx_xoff_frames: 0
     rx_mac_ctrl_frames: 0
     rx_filtered_packets: 113311
     rx_ftq_discards: 0
     rx_discards: 0
     rx_fw_discards: 0
```

(`ifconfig eno1 |grep errors`) output :

```
RX errors 0  dropped 93  overruns 0  frame 0
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

(`lshw -C network`) output :

```
*-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 20
       serial: d4:ae:52:ca:0f:6e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bnx2 driverversion=2.2.6 duplex=full firmware=7.4.8 bc 7.4.0 NCSI 2.0.11 ip=(serverip) latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:c0000000-c1ffffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       logical name: eno2
       version: 20
       serial: d4:ae:52:ca:0f:6f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bnx2 driverversion=2.2.6 duplex=half firmware=7.4.8 bc 7.4.0 NCSI 2.0.11 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 memory:c2000000-c3ffffff
```

Comment: Was there a reason you chose a 5 year old version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @pbhj because we use libraries only works on 18.04.6

Comment: There are dropped packets ... First thing to do, check your twisted pair cable for damage or change it with another one and check ... Might help to check statistics with e.g. `ethtool -S eno1`

Comment: @Raffa thanks for your replay ... i will update question with ethtool -S eno1 output now and about change cable i was say its from ( OneProvider ... scaleway partner ) hosting company ....

Comment: 93 packets of Rx (received) out of half-a-billion doesn't seem like a significant error?

Comment: @pbhj you mean 93 packets dropped ??!!

Comment: Yes, I meant that 93 dropped packets, of a total number of (received) packets ~500 billion seems good. `ethtool -S | grep drop` shows 1783 for me, in the last 30 minutes or so, no problems at all with my connection. The 1Gbps at best is contended bandwidth, so perhaps others are already hogging it. It's a little hard to tell from your description which end you're talking about: you're saying that "the download speed is about 100kbps", so that's download to the server (on OneProvider), but downloading from where? You need higher bandwidth across the whole route to get the full speed.

Comment: Also that multicast address points to "Scaleway Dedibox" (presumably an upstream supplier), their page shows most 1Gbps connectivity servers have  [bw much lower than 250Mbps](https://console.online.net/en/order/server). `mtr` will show where packets are being dropped, fwiw. If you have install privileges then `sudo apt install speedtest-cli` and check the server. Then do the same at the other end of the link.

Comment: @pbhj the speedtest always give me about 850mb download and about 900mb upload

Comment: Only other thing to easily direct you to is using `tracepath -b <DESTINATION_IP_ADDRESS>` to check that the pmtu between the two ends of your connection is OK. You have 1500, sometimes it needs to be lower. Set it with eg `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<YOUR_CONNECTION>.nmconnection`.